# Syntax color in Emacs lucid for text between EOF delimiters

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I want to modify the color line for the syntax between EOF delimiters.
I've searched about this specific topic, but I haven't found anything.

This is the bash script:

```
gnuplot -persist <<EOF
set title 'grafico'
plot "salida.txt"
EOF
```